# Bluetooth LE (RxAppCompatActivity) - Debugging

Tags: android, debugging, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scan all available bluetooth (LE) devices with my galaxy tablet in Android Studio but the devices don't show up. I can only see all the devices when I run this application without debugging.

> ScanActivity: devices are shown in recycler view when I run the code but not when I try to debug.

```
public class ScanActivity extends RxAppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private ScanResultsAdapter resultsAdapter;
    private IBluetoothService bluetoothService;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        configureResultList();
        handleScanResult();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intentBluetooth = new Intent(this, BluetoothLEService.class);
        bindService(intentBluetooth, connectionBluetooth, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        doShortScan();
    }

    public void handleScanResult() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (boundBluetooth) {
                if (bluetoothService.hasScanResult())
                    resultsAdapter.addScanResult(bluetoothService.getScanResult());
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted to better understand your issue and find the proper solution. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app and then go to android studio toolbar:

```
Run -> Attach To Process
```

also make sure you have connected device as MTP option.

If still you are unable to resolve the issue try restarting Android studio and your device as well.

Comment: MTP is already set - I have also restartet my device and android studio. still not working...

Comment: try developer options and make sure you have USB debugging on.

Comment: USB-Debugging is also on